# Firebase push notifications for mobile

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase, apple-push-notifications

I would like to know if I can use firebase to notify mobile app users for their custom defined changes in the stock exchange market for example. This information can be get from an public API. 
I know that push notifications can be send using FCM, but can I use functions and other Firebase features for tis too?

Comment: yes, yes you can.

Comment: For an example of sending push notifications with Cloud Functions, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens

Comment: thanks guys. functions can only be used for databases right? so I first have to create and update the firebase database somehow. This the part where I need some advice

Comment: Functions can also be used over https if you are not using other firebase services